# Select data from big MLM data

Tags: php, mysql

I think I need some advice to solve my case. I have a MLM application which using PHP and MySQL. The problem is in the member schema. Here the case :

1. Every parent can have maximum 10 child, and each child can have maximum 10 child too.
2. In my application, everyone who trying to register need a referral which mean need a parent.
3. The MLM system just support for 10 levels, it's mean one people may have 10.000.000.000 downline.
4. This is the main case. if there's a parent with 10 child, and someone tried to register with that parent referral (which mean the parent will have 11 child), then that people will becoming granchild for one of the 10 children.

illustration :

A (Parent)

A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10. (child)

then, there's some one want to register to becoming A's child (A11), then the system must detect if A has 10 child (max) and the A11 will become child of A1 (if A1 not yet have 10 child). But If A1 have 10 child already, then A11 will become child of A2, and so on.

The main problem is, if I select data from database like :

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE refferal='A'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 10) {
/* Another Select with Loop */
}
?>
```

that will be slowdown the application if the application already had a big data. Then, what should I do? I just want to check if the parent has 10 child already, the new member will be the grandchild, but if the each child has 10 child already, the new member will be grandchildren. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I don't understand the logic, if child 11 can become a member just the same, why limit the number of children to 10?

Comment: sorry, it's cause I had bad english to describe that.

child 11 can be member, but the refferal will be automaticaly become the one of 10 childs.

Comment: Your description is fine, I just don't understand why you would use the 10-child limit.

Comment: You actually need to check in the database, if your parent has alsready 10 children. Since your logic is a Breadth-first search, this will become more load intensive for each child you add, because you basically have to check for each previously added member who referred to the parent or one of his children. You can either change the logic or live with the runtime.

Comment: it set to 10, just to limit, so everyone may have downline. so it will be fair if everyone had benefit from the downline. jeroen


PhilippMaurer, so there's no other way or effective way to check if every single child has 10 child or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can not evaluate a free "spot" without querying the database, but instead of querying each parent separately, you can reduce the number of queries by selecting all users with a free "spot" of a specific hierarchy level:

```
$parents = NULL;
do {
    if ($parents === NULL) {
        $parentsQuery = 'SELECT t.user_id FROM table_name as t WHERE t.parent_id IN [' . implode(',', $parents)  . '];';
        $parentResult = msqli_query($dbConnection, $parentQuery);
        $parents = $parentResult->fetch_all();
        $parents = array_map(function($parentRow){
                return $parentRow['user_id'];
            }, $parents);
    } else {
        $parents = [$_POST['parent']];
    }
    $query = 'SELECT parent.user_id FROM table_name as parent JOIN table_name as child ON child.parent_id = parent.user_id WHERE parent.user_id IN [' . implode(',', $parents)  . '] AND count(child.*) < 10 GROUP_BY parent.user_id ORDER BY parent.user_id;';
    $result = msqli_query($dbConnection, $query);
while ($result->num_rows === 0 && !empty($parents));

// First parent that has less than 10 children
$parent= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['user_id'];
```

The code might decrease your runtime, but will still get slow the deeper the loop needs to go.
Due to the maximum nested level, this code will run at most 20 queries on your database. (10 children queries, which are very load intensive at the deeper levels and 10 fast, but more RAM intensive parent queries)

The code was also not tested yet, but is only intended to lead you to a faster solution. It needs to be improved regarding security and stability as well.